# hatom-entry errors on the Google snippet test

Tags: wordpress, rich-snippets

Almost sure that I'm not the first one that has this question but when I test my [(WordPress) page](http://www.google.nl/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://host-reviews.nl/webhosting-reviews-yourhosting) on Google Snippet Test Tool I got hatom-enty errors like:

```
hatom-feed

hatom-entry:
    
Fout: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.

Fout: Missing required field "entry-title".

Fout: Missing required field "updated".

Fout: Missing required hCard "author".
```

I found some [tutorials](http://urbanstoic.com/how-to-fix-google-hfeed-or-hcard-warnings) about this but that is for standard WordPress themes. I'm using Inovado from ThemeForest and I can't figure out in which file I have to edit this data.

Someone familiar with this?

I also got problems with snippet review... Good in testresults but doesn't show up in de Google Search Results. Don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

You can Add this code to the function.php file in your theme's directory and it will solve the problems.

```
//mod content
function hatom_mod_post_content ($content) {
if ( in_the_loop() && !is_page() ) {
$content = '<span class="entry-content">'.$content.'</span>';
 }
 return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'hatom_mod_post_content');

//add hatom data
function add_mod_hatom_data($content) {
$t = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$author = get_the_author();
$title = get_the_title();
if(is_single()) {
    $content .= '<div class="hatom-extra"><span class="entry-title">'.$title.'</span> was    last modified: <span class="updated"> '.$t.'</span> by <span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">'.$author.'</span></span></div>';
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_mod_hatom_data');
```

The code contains 2 functions. The first function will use the WordPress filter hook for “the_content” to add the class of “entry-content” to the article. To add in the other essential hAtom fields, the second function will add a short sentence to the end of your post article, which contains updated time, post title and author, with required microdata.